# How to merge table cells in Eclipse RCP Table control?

Tags: eclipse, merge, rcp, cells

My question is: I've an Eclipse RCP table in my view. The table has gridlines Visible and everything is fine. But I want all the cells of first row of the table to be merged as a single row in run-time GUI. How can I achieve this functionality ? Please, I don't expect something like adding a text over the first row obstructing it. If any API level functionality or any clues to do this are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The swt table is a native widget and does not allow you any span, neither in columns nor in rows. Even OwnerDraw (custom cell rendering) does not support this. The only way I see that could allow you to achieve this kind of hack is the swt table editor which allows you to place controls above cells:

http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#tableeditor

The table editor tracks the position of single cells and positions controls above them. It hides controls when a cell is not in edit mode, show's them when the cell is in edit mode. You'd have to deactivate this default behavior and make sure the controls are always shown - this should be fairly easy.
The more challenging part would be that you'd have to find out how to place the controls above 2 or more (and not a single) cells.

The only swt control I know to support span is the nebula grid. Grid is a custom control (no native widget) and therefore offers far more possibilites.

http://eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/grid/grid.php
http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.nebula/org.eclipse.swt.nebula.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/nebula/snippets/grid/GridSnippet2.java?root=Technology_Project&view=co

Comment: Thank you adietisheim for the answer. Actually I'd already used the Table Editor for data Editing purposes in the cells and also I had used the Nebulla Grid control for custom TableHeaders(esp. for Table Column grouping purposes ). But I had not done any hack like you have answered. I'll try to the best to achieve the objectives. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

u can use GC api to do the needs in table. u can span between two columns. 
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/Maketextspanmultiplecolumns.htm

Comment: While this may answer the question, please post the relevant section of the link in your answer. From the [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): _Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._